# How can I get alerted when the Firebase service goes down?

Tags: firebase

I know I can manually go to **status.firebase.com** but I need to be alerted immediately when my firebase app goes down and when it comes back up.

I thought I could possibly use [dingitsup.com](http://www.dingitsup.com) to send myself a notification, but i don't know where to point it.

I would also like to have the option of automatically displaying a message to my users when Firebase is down to let them know the system is down and its not a problem on their end.  Is there a [Zapier](https://zapier.com) integration i could use to achieve this?

Any help would be great!  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically, you could use a service like [Pingdom](http://pingdom.com/) to send yourself a notification, and could ping an endpoint on `your-firebase.firebaseio.com/some-public-endpoint.json`.

Also, [@FirebaseStatus](https://twitter.com/firebasestatus) is a good resource actively updated by the Firebase folks.

Comment: thanks, i will try this as well and see what works best for me

Answer (score 1):

Could you write something to use the connection state?

https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html (broken)
new link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities

I use something similar in my apps to detect if the user has a connection, and display a notice if they don't.

Comment: This is a good idea but it would not help if firebase is already down to begin with when a user tries to log in

Comment: Scratch that, i guess if they are able to hit the CDN and download the files my app could tell them that firebase is having problems

Answer (score 0):

I just figured a way

```
Firebase.enableLogging(function(logMessage) {
    if(logMessage && logMessage.indexOf("Long-poll script failed to load") !== -1 && navigator.onLine){
        console.error('Its dead Jim! Firebase seems to be down for this user');
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how firebase works under the hoods but I've seen users connected in a previously open tab and if they open a new tab firebase won't connect when it's down.

This logging function is called a lot, and when firebase is down our console.error will be call every ~5s or something. 
Make sure to [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) whatever you'll do in the console.error's place.